# Ruby: Getting access to a subclass constant

Tags: ruby, constants, subclass, class-method

Why does the following not work?

```
class Foo
    def self.keyletters
        self::KEYLETTERS
    end
end

class Baz < Foo
    KEYLETTERS = "US"
end

puts Foo.keyletters
```

I have seen questions for similar problems (eg. here: [Have a parent class's method access the subclass's constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014764/have-a-parent-classs-method-access-the-subclasss-constants)), but in my case Foo.keyletters is a class-method, not an instance method. I am getting

```
uninitialized constant Foo::KEYLETTERS (NameError)
```

Answer (score 3):

When class `A` inherits class `B` or includes/extends module `C`, then `A` gets whatever `B` and `C` have, in addition to its own constants, variables and methods. `B` and `C` are not affected by that.

In your case, `Baz` is a subclass of `Foo`. So `Baz` has whatever `Foo` has, in addition to `Baz::KEYLETTERS`. `Foo` does not have anything in addition. Particularly, there is no `Foo::KEYLETTERS`.

Comment: But how do you explain the behaviour that the link shared in the question says?

Comment: I don't think that's true. Check out this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014764/have-a-parent-classs-method-access-the-subclasss-constants, in which Animal can " puts self.class::NOISE" without ever declaring NOISe itself (see answer by Phrogz, second code block). Also, modules get access to the instance variables of the classes they are included in; so I don't think your statement is correct for modules either.

Comment: LPD, McKrassy You are confusing what the receiver is. Look carefully. In those cases, the constructor is applied to `Dog`, and not `Animal`. `Dog` has all the extra things; `Animal` does not.